# Scan source files from both /src and /build when perform annotation processing

Tags: android, realm, annotation-processing

Due to some reasons, I am developing an annotation processor for my Android app to generate classes which extend `RealmObject` and are annotated with `@RealmClass` and `@PrimaryKey`. And I supposed that Realm will generate interface and mediator codes from the classes generated by my processor. But it's not working.

```
// Generated in app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/test/RealmRecord.java
// package and imports
@RealmClass
public class RealmRecord extends RealmObject {
    @Primary
    long id;
    String content;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I found that in my Android Studio environment, the annotation processor seems not searching the files in *app/build/generated/source/apt/xxx*... so Realm's processor cannot find my classes and process further..

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Realm annotation processor. See [this line](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/48197be15f754cefa55eefb8794f01f202d58fa0/realm/realm-annotations-processor/src/main/java/io/realm/processor/RealmProcessor.java#L139):

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    // Don't run this processor in subsequent runs. We created everything in the first one.
    if (hasProcessedModules) {
        return CONSUME_ANNOTATIONS;
    }

    ...

    // more buggy code down there
}
```

Their processor violates annotation processing contract: instead of incrementally processing new files during each round they abandon the processing after the first round.

Comment: If this is an error, a Github issue should be filed.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Feel free to do so if you use Realm. I don't, and convincing people that they should change their "working" code is often too much pain to do so in one's free time.